# Where should I put comma in the following row of adjectives?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, coordination

This is the original text:

> purple metallic, glass bong

[Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adjective/) says that you should put a comma where you could also add "and." According to this, the text above should be:

> purple, metallic glass bong (purple and metallic glass bong)

Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammarly [is](https://www.grammar.com/commas-and-coordinate-adjectives) [correct](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000072.htm) in this case. When two adjectives *independently* modify the same noun, the adjectives are separated from each other by commas.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't sound right - *metallic glass, purple bong.* It should if these were coordinate adjectives. They should be able to switch places with each other.

Comment: @AIQ Colors usually come before material. "Purple, metallic glass bong" sounds okay to me (as long as "metallic" modifies "glass" rather than "bong"; if not we need a second comma).

Comment: (And in the case metallic does modify glass, think it should be "purple, metallic-glass bong" with a hyphen.)

Comment: Let's say it's metallic-glass (with the hyphen). Then this is an adjective of material. You are right - first comes color and then material (adjective order). But that is not the point I am trying to make. I agree with you - it should be color-material-noun. What I am trying to point out is that the comma is used when the adjectives are from the same group, they can switch positions, and you can fit an "and" between them. OP's sentence, I feel, does not pass the two-step test for coordinate adjectives. Purple and metallic-glass are cumulative adjectives (which do not use commas).

Comment: We would say "a black leather jacket" and not "a black, leather jacket". If we say "a black, leather jacket" then we are implying these are valid: "a black and leather jacket" and "a leather, black jacket" - these are actually not valid. What do you think?

Comment: @AIQ I realized that you are right. What should be, then, the correct order of my example? Purple metallic glass bong without commas?